# Apache htaccess rewrite rule subtract a number

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For some reason I have to subtract a number from `$1` here, which will be a digit:

```
RewriteRule ^categories\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)?$ /at.php?-category_$1  [L,NC]
```

I want to pass `$1-4` into category number here. For example, if URL is:
http://localhost/categories/12/xyz
Category id will be 12-4 which will be 8.

Can we do some simple plus minus operations here?

Comment: This would be doable with `RewriteMap` calling an external script, but if you are in control of the `at.php` script, I suppose it would be a lot easier to handle the change there - if you need to determine whether that script should do the arithmetic or not, perhaps pass an additional query string param from `RewriteRule` as a flag that the subtraction should take place. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html